# How to show the current age in months using twig, symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, date, twig

I have a project where I want to display the current age of an infant in months, also have a code that calculates and displays the age in years, but I want to have it in months. This is mi code.

```
<td>{% if entity.birthdate %}{{ ('now'|date('Y') - entity.birthdate|date('Y') - 1) + ('now'|date('Y-m-d')|date('U') - entity.birthdate|date('Y-m-d')|date('U') >= 0 ? 1 : 0) }}{% endif %}</td>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: If you want to have the total number of months, you can do smt like this

`{#  entity.birthdate is string or DateTime objects #}
{% set difference = date('now').diff(date(entity.birthdate)) %}
{% set months = difference.format('Y')*12 + difference.format('m') %} `

if  you count remaining days to a month you have to check, if day are greater 1 then add on 1 to months

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's tempting to compute values in templates/views, it's best to separate logic and presentation.

I imagine that displaying a baby's age is something that you might want again in the future, so let's make it a method on the `entity` (i.e. *a function of the `entity` class*).

```
// entity.php
class person
{
    // Assumption: $birthdate is a DateTime object.
    protected $birthdate;

    // getAge() outputs something like this: '1 years, 1 months, 8 days old.'
    public function getAge()
    {
        $now = new \DateTime('now');
        $age = $this->getBirthdate();
        $difference = $now->diff($age);

        return $difference->format('%y years, %m months, %d days old.');
    }

    public function getBirthdate()
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    public function setBirthdate($birthdate)
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then in your Twig file you can access the `getAge` method:

```
{{ entity.age }}
```

Because I was interesting in knowing how, you can also do this in Twig ;)

```
{{ date('now').diff((date('2014-1-3'))).format('%y years %m months %d days old') }}
```

[Try it on twigFiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/awrebp)

Comment: Thanks, it was very useful